# Mitzvos on which the only b'racha is birkas "Shehechiyanu"

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, shehecheyanu

I saw in the name of the *Or Zaru'a* and others that one does not make a *b'racha* before writing a *sefer Torah* even though it is a positive *mitzva* with an action associated because (among other reasons) one can be reasonably certain that he will not perform the *mitzva* exactly correctly since it is such a hard thing to do. However, one still says "*Shehechiyanu*" upon performance of this great *mitzva*. This led me to the question. . .

Performance of what other *mitzvos* warrants only the (time-based but not intrinsic) *birkas "Shehechiyanu"* but no *birkas hamitzva*?

Comment: Why'd you make this one community wiki? Just curious.

Comment: @Isaac Moses That is a good question. I just wanted to experiment.

Comment: seems like a riddle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Matanos laevyonim*, *mishloach manos*, and *s'udas purim*. Source: *Magen Avraham* 692:1, cited *l'maase* in *Aruch Hashulchan* :2 and *Mishna B'rura* :1. (More precisely, that's a source for saying *shehecheyanu* on these *mitzvos*, not for not making another *b'racha* on them.)

Answer (score 4):

The Mitzvos of **Yom Kippur**.

Comment: Do we in fact say the _b'racha_ on the _mitzvos_, or is it on the _z'man_ only (like we say one for every _yom tov_)?

Comment: Chaim B. Sommers, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for this answer! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking register/login, above.

Answer (score 3):

2 that come to mind are:

**Sukkah** where meikar hadin shehecheyanu should be made at the time of the building of the sukkah (Aruch haShulchan b'shem shas bavli, yerushalmi and tosefta 641:3 and

**Chanukah lights** where even if a person will not light himself, he makes the other brachos upon seeing a chanukah light (Shulchan Aruch 676:3 and Aruch haShulchan 676:6-7), although one can say that the shehecheyanu is on the day, but the bracha was only set upon seeing/lighting candles.

Comment: Re: sukkah. You are right that the shehechiyanu is essentially on building it, but as building it is not a mitzva, does this really qualify as a mitzva with only a shehechiyanu, or is it more similar to countless other examples of lone shehechiyanus on non-mitzvot (eg. buying a car)?